# Can run jar file. JNI error after maven build. Classpath can be broken

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, classpath

I am struggling to run my .jar file created with maven.
When I run my project in th InteliJ IDE it works fine, but when I build it with with maven I can not to run it.

Command used to run run:

> java -cp target\xmpp-server.jar com.wedevol.xmpp.server.EntryPoint

Output of run:

```
c:\Repos\remindanyoneserverapp>java -cp target\xmpp-server.jar com.wedevol.xmpp.server.EntryPoint
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

Maven comand "mvn package" output:

```
c:\Repos\remindanyoneserverapp>mvn package

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< com.wedevol.xmpp.server:xmppserver2 >-----------------
[INFO] Building FCM XMPP Server 0.0.4
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ xmppserver2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory c:\Repos\remindanyoneserverapp\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ xmppserver2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ xmppserver2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory c:\Repos\remindanyoneserverapp\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xmppserver2 ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ xmppserver2 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ xmppserver2 ---
[INFO] Building jar: c:\Repos\remindanyoneserverapp\target\xmpp-server.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.312 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-26T21:32:37+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

POM.xml file:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.wedevol.xmpp.server</groupId>
 <artifactId>xmppserver2</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.4</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>FCM XMPP Server</name>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <smack.version>4.2.3</smack.version>
  <json-simple.version>1.1.1</json-simple.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
   <artifactId>smack-java7</artifactId>
   <version>${smack.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
   <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
   <version>${smack.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
   <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
   <version>${smack.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
   <version>${json-simple.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
     <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
     <version>5.9.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.46</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <finalName>xmpp-server</finalName>
  <plugins>
   <!-- Set a JDK compiler level -->
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>${java.version}</source>
     <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

I suppose it is problem with the classpath. I tried to get the classpath generated with the IDE but I can not find it...
Please give any advice how to start with classpath if this is the case.
Maybe Maven can be configured better to build all dependecies into jar.

Comment: I manage to do it:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pom.xml had to updated with following:

```js
a
```

```html
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```